# AnkhSVN Project Branch/Switch bug?

Tags: ankhsvn

In a VS 2010 solution with multiple projects, if I right-click a project and have Ankh create a Project Branch and I check the box to switch to branch after creation, it correctly creates a branch of just the project, but it switches the *solution* to that project - resulting in it dumping the solution files and all the other projects/files from the directory.

I was able to reproduce this by creating a new blank solution, added 3 console applications, add solution to svn, do the project branch on one of the projects, and everything else got dumped from the folder. VS still shows the solution and all the projects/files, but are marked as missing.

If I create the project branch and don't select the checkbox to automatically switch, I can manually switch the project (right-click on the project, subversion, switch) and it works just fine.

Why is it doing a solution switch from the project branch dialog - am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug?

AnkhSVN v2.4.11610.27, Visual Studio 2010 v10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

EDIT: Same happens in VS 2008 and VS2012

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: Yes? 2.4.11610 is still the current version - nothing has changed - so I'm not sure what you're asking. I just tried it again and it still does a bad switch.

Comment: Still bugged in v2.4.12012.1

Comment: Still bugged in v2.5.12040

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is a case with Anksvn, what it does is it creates a branch for complete solution and does switches complete solution to for that branch.

Comment: Sorry, but I confirmed that it (correctly) branched the single project and not the entire solution. Looking at the repository, branch clearly shows just the single project folder and not the entire solution. If I do a _Project_ Branch but do not check the box to "Switch to branch after creation", I can then do a Switch Project and it works as expected.